# Cannot Recover Reputation Points After Migration

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, migration, daily-reputation-limit

Apologies if this has already been reported, or is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or whatever. I couldn't find anything addressing it.

After a question I answered was migrated to a different site, I lost 25 rep from 1 upvote and the accept. That makes perfect sense; I gained the points on the other site, so no net loss.

The problem is I already hit rep cap today, and after losing the points I still can't gain them back from subsequent upvotes. Exhibit A:

[image]

Should not those subsequent upvotes count? Part of the loss was in upvotes, so I should expect to gain it back through upvotes just as well.

Comment: If the votes on the migrated question were received before today, they will not count towards *today's* repcap. Instead, they will count towards the repcap on the day(s) that they were cast.

Comment: @Mysticial, so because I gained those points on a day I didn't hit rep cap, and it got migrated on a day that I did, it is expected that they couldn't be recovered?

Comment: Correct. It's as if the votes never existed.

Comment: Ok, I think the confusion comes from the -25 listed *today*, when really it's calculating as if it subtracted on the days I gained the points. Had I hit rep cap on the day of the upvote, a later upvote that day would give me rep it previously didn't?

Comment: Correct. It might show up weird in your rep history. But the total amount will be correct. (the later upvote will have given you the rep)

Comment: **OH**, now I see! my rep reduced 15 points (from 4606 to 4591) when it displayed -25. That's it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes sense and is by design. You can only get 200 points from sources subject to the cap, and that doesn't change just because of the migration. Looking at your profile just now, you have hit the cap again, anyway. So, you haven't lost any points (or opportunities for points) that you otherwise would have gotten.

[image]

Comment: (I didn't downvote you, but) fundamentally I gained 200 upvote points today, then lost 10 upvote points (of the 25 from the migration), then didn't gain 10 back from any subsequent upvotes. I am still considered to be at the cap, despite only a net 190 vote gain

Comment: Looking at your profile, I still see [**200 points from upvotes**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3130539/mhlester?tab=reputation&sort=post). Can you explain where you see only a 190 point gain?

Comment: 190 *net* gain if I subtract the 10 from the migrated question

Comment: Why are you subtracting 10, though? The point is that *today* you got enough to hit the cap. If you lost an upvote from a prior day, that didn't count towards today's cap, as @Mysticial pointed out, so it doesn't affect the math for today's cap. If you lost an upvote from today, you hit the cap again, so you're still not missing out on anything you could have gotten otherwise.

Comment: I lost an upvote today, so I expected to be able to gain it back. But I guess that loss is back-dated to the day I had gained it.